# Can't install agent for Cassandra in Docker container

Tags: cassandra, docker, datastax, agent

I have successfully set up a two node Cassandra cluster using Docker containers on two separate machines. When I try to administer the cluster using OpCenter it fails because the DataStax Agents are not installed.

Automatic installation of the agents via OpCenter fails.

I open up a bash shell in the Cassandra Docker container and try to install the agent manually, but that fails, too. It appears that the agent installer is expecting sudo support, which is not present in the container.

So, I'm wondering what the "right way" to install the agent into a docker container would be. Anyone done this? Any thoughts?

Comment: is there a reason you can't run the installer as root, or as a user with sudo privileges?

Comment: The installer expects some sudo support. The first failure is not finding the /etc/sudoers file, but that seems to be only the first layer of the onion. The docker container is very minimal (as it should be, or you sort of defeat the purpose of containers), and only root is the only user. Assuming you have security on your metal this should be fine (I think). 

It may be that the only solution for using agents is to have a fatter container.

However, I'm sort of surprised that the official Cassandra container doesn't seem to support agents. It makes me feel as if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Did you build a docker container or you are using a preexisting one?

Comment: Used the official Cassandra image (https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/).

Comment: I am facing the same problem, any ideas?